# Power Automate - Unable to get JSON content for Parsing

Tags: json, power-automate, powerapps

I upload a JSON file from Power Apps to a SharePoint folder by running a Power Automate flow.

[image]
[image][image]

At this point I am trying to get the saved JSON file's contents in order to Parse it. My Compose step returns an error msg

> 404 "message": "The response is not in a JSON format." "innerError":
> "Cannot read server response."

Can you please help me out? Thank you

[Edited]
When I ran the Power Automate flow I get the following output

[image]

The JSON content is in the blue rectangle and that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to decode the base64 contents. Try:

```
base64ToString( triggerBody()['file']['contentBytes'] )
```

Comment: Hi Sam, I tried your solution but I still cannot get the JSON content to parse. I tried the "base64" function in the "Create file" step and then in the following "Compose" step, but with no luck. I can't see the actual JSON content of the file I have just uploaded to the SharePoint folder.

Comment: Update your question with the output of the Compose so we can see what it is returning. And which step is getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sam's idea, instead of base64ToString() I used the **decodeBase64()** instead, in the next Compose step and I got the full JSON content.